# How do I fix Visual Studio (2013) namespace collision when moving files

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

When moving files around in a project I ran into some pretty frustrating namespace collision issues.  After the fact I learned a better way to move the files but I'm hoping to find a solution.  Here is what I experienced:

After moving files via cut/paste I had a namespace collision (I have many pages with the same name in different folders e.g. Foo/Add.aspx and Bar/Add.aspx).  When I moved a page, associated code behind and designer to a new folder I had a namespace collision.  When I updated the namespace VS showed the little red marker indicating it wanted to "help" me by renaming.  I had VS go ahead and "help" only to find after several attempts that it was also re-naming the file in the folder I had moved from e.g.  When I renamed Foo/Add.aspx VS was also changing the namespace for Bar/Add.aspx

Does anyone know why this is? Or how to avoid it? I fixed it by manually changing all my namespaces and not allowing VS to "help" me out.

Comment: It would help if you actually gave examples of the old and new namespaces, rather than file and folder names. Class namespaces (what I assume you're referring to, since that's the kind VS cares about) do not have anything to do with file names or locations in .NET.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The folder is the namespace for the contained .aspx .aspx.cs and designer

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options:

- if you have Resharper then use the *Move* function
- don't copy/paste with a project, instead you should drag/drop - that way the proj file is updated and files maintain their relationship (i.e. when you have generated code behind, etc). Then the moment you've dropped, go and change the namespace in the dropped file.
- create a new file in the target folder, then just copy the contents (everything inside the namespace declaration) of the old file across. The new file will already automatically have an appropriate namespace defined.

None of this tidies up any code that references the old code that has been replicated/moved. You'll have to fix those references yourself, unless you use Resharper (which does that for you as part of the move).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I learned after the fact.  What I'm searching for is why VS changed both namespaces with its utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about class namespaces, the problem is that VS has no way to know which "Add" namespace you want to rename. It just renames all the ones (in its current scope) that match that current name to the new name. If you want to avoid that happening, they will need to *at least* be in different VS Projects. VS does not care about file names or paths, except to the minimum degree needed to find them for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

what I do is, I always create my class in the destination project and copy the content of the source class to the destination class. in this way you will be safe.

I doubt if there is a any magical way to avoid that problem.